# jquery Ajax Value Not Save correctly in Mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I Am Using Jquery Ajax code

```
$("#savecustomer").click(function() {
  var customer = {};
  debugger;
  customer.Customerid = $("#userid").text();
  customer.PhoneNo = $("#txtphoneno").val();
  customer.Email = $("#txtemail").val();
  customer.Password = $("#txtpwd").val();
  customer.Name = $("#txtname").val();
  customer.Shiping_Address = $("#txtsa").val();
  customer.Pin = $("#txtpin").val();
  $.ajax({
    url: '/Home/AddCustomerInfo',
    method: 'Post',
    dataType: "json",
    data: '{customer: ' + JSON.stringify(customer) + '}',
    success: function() {
      alertify.log("Your Data saved Successfully...", "Success", 3000);
    },
    error: function() {
      alertify.log("Data Not Save ......", "error", 3000);
    }
  });
});
```

and Mvc Controller Function name

> public void AddCustomerInfo(Customerinformation customer)

```
   public void AddCustomerInfo(Customerinformation customer)
    {

        using (TestEntities db = new TestEntities())
        {
            db.spAddCustomer(customer.Customerid, customer.PhoneNo, customer.Email, customer.Password, customer.Name, customer.Shiping_Address, customer.Pin);

        }
    }
```

this function execute storepeocedure and save some data in database.

when run my code then data is not brind to database int field insert 0 and varchar field insert null.
like that[DataBase Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pzk0D.png)

Comment: Change you `data` option to `data: customer,` and it will bind fine, but your code suggests numerous other problems with your view. If your generating it correctly, then its simply `data: $('form').serialize()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
 $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("AddCustomerInfo", "Home")',
            data: JSON.stringify({ customer: customer }),
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function() {
            alertify.log("Your Data saved Successfully...", "Success", 3000);
            },
            error: function() {
            alertify.log("Data Not Save ......", "error", 3000);
            }

        });
```